# CSS variables: Sugar syntax exists?

Tags: css, css-variables

Instead writing:

```
:root {
    --pc: gray;
    --sc: lightgray;
}

var(--pc)
```

Is there an even shorter syntax, at least shorter than `var(--pc)`?

Comment: What's not short enough about `var(--pc)`?

Comment: change `--pc` with `--p` and it will be shorter

Comment: I don't think it's not short but just `--pc` would be shorter.

Comment: "Is there an even shorter syntax?" Nope.

Comment: Nop, but try looking for a preprocessor that does something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. The `var()` notation is there so the CSS parser can distinguish a custom property expression from any other identifier in a style declaration (in much the same way the `calc()` notation exists to distinguish arithmetic expressions) as well as providing a way to specify a fallback, while maintaining compatibility with preprocessors that already have their own variable reference notations.

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

*Pure CSS* does not allow you to omit the `var()`.

However, there are an abundance of preprocessors out there, each with its own set of syntax modifications. Perhaps there exists one with a shorter variable-accessing syntax, but this is beside the point of the question.